# Positioning text in NSTableCellView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am experiencing a problem in Cocoa where the text in the textField of an NSTableCellView is being cut off when I define the rowHeight of the tableView.  It should be noted that all elements are being created programmatically.  I am a bit new to Cocoa and am aware that a lot of what is below may well be below the quality of a dog's breakfast and suggestions are welcomed.

My table is created thusly:

```
 ....
 NSScrollView * tableContainer = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, returnView.frame.size.width, 100)];
 NSTableView * tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, tableContainer.frame.size.width, 100)];
 [tableView setRowHeight:30];
 NSLog(@"tableView was created with a row height of %f", [tableView rowHeight]);
 ....
```

Within the viewForTableColumn method, I do the following:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {

// get an existing cell with the MyView identifier if it exists

NSTableCellView *result = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"MyView" owner:self];

// There is no existing cell to reuse so we will create a new one
if (result == nil) {

    result = [[NSTableCellView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, [tableView rowHeight])];

    // the identifier of the NSTextField instance is set to MyView. This
    // allows it to be re-used
    result.identifier = @"MyView";
}

// result is now guaranteed to be valid, either as a re-used cell
// or as a new cell, so set the stringValue of the cell to the
// nameArray value at row
NSLog(@"tableView row height is %f", [tableView rowHeight]);
NSLog(@"Cell bounds is {%f,%f} %f x %f", result.bounds.origin.x, result.bounds.origin.y, result.bounds.size.width, result.frame.size.height);
NSTextField *cellTF = [[NSTextField alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, result.bounds.size.height)];
NSLog(@"TextField size is {%f,%f} %f x %f", cellTF.frame.origin.x, cellTF.frame.origin.y, cellTF.frame.size.width, cellTF.frame.size.height);
[result addSubview:cellTF];
result.textField = cellTF;
[cellTF setBordered:NO];
[cellTF setEditable:NO];
[cellTF setDrawsBackground:NO];
result.textField.stringValue = @"hello";

NSLog(@"cell string value is now %@", [[result textField] stringValue]);

return result;
```

}

My log output is as follows (duplicate log entries for each row redacted):

```
WHCCConnect[26394:f07] tableView was created with a row height of 30.000000
WHCCConnect[26394:f07] tableView row height is 30.000000
WHCCConnect[26394:f07] Cell bounds is {0.000000,0.000000} 200.000000 x 30.000000
WHCCConnect[26394:f07] TextField size is {0.000000,0.000000} 100.000000 x 30.000000
WHCCConnect[26394:f07] cell string value is now hello row!
```

The actual result on the screen:

[image]

However, if I **do not** specify the rowHeight when creating the table, like this:

```
    NSScrollView * tableContainer = [[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, returnView.frame.size.width, 100)];
    NSTableView * tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, tableContainer.frame.size.width, 100)];
    //[tableView setRowHeight:30];
```

I get this as the output (duplicate log entries for each row redacted):

```
WHCCConnect[26458:f07] tableView was created with a row height of 17.000000
WHCCConnect[26458:f07] tableView row height is 17.000000
WHCCConnect[26458:f07] Cell bounds is {0.000000,0.000000} 203.000000 x 17.000000
WHCCConnect[26458:f07] TextField size is {0.000000,0.000000} 100.000000 x 17.000000
WHCCConnect[26458:f07] cell string value is now hello row!
```

and the resulting table looks like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?  How can I get these blasted rows to size properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView heightOfRow:(NSInteger)row;
```